# Does any body know where I can find my ISP SMTP server address for my localhost testing?

Tags: php, localhost

I'm using road runner and is there a free smtp server to use with wamp just in case i can't use my isp?

Answer (score 1):

If you send fewer than 500 messages/day from each email address (and you can have multiple email addresses), you can use [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/). The problem with anything free is that free SMTP servers are prey to spammers, so they'll tend to have limits and other restrictions.